# UI or the view layer is most predictable when it is described as a pure function of the application state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am novice to Redux and following a tutorial on [redux](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-the-reducer-function#/tab-transcript) where I found a comment -

> UI or the view layer is most predictable when it is described as a pure function of the application state

Can someone explain me it in layman terms what do we mean by the predictability of UI when describing as a pure function of an application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view layer should not do any data manipulation, it should simply output the data it is presented. This prevents anyone from making any mistakes during that data manipulation which would result in unsafe data (If the view did a matrix rotation on the input, it would also need to revert that matrix rotation in order to ensure the data stays consistent).

Let's say there is a game board with a score (Checkers with a score of how many jumps you've done for example). It would be "pure" to have the score stored somewhere in the `state` (each time you jump an opponent's piece, increment the score), it would be "impure" to have the view calculate the score (There were initially 12 pieces, after iterating through the board we can see 5 left, which means we've jumped 7).

In another scenario, we may wish to alter the state while calculating the score (if you were making a Rubik's Cube solver, the score may be "how close is the solution to the optimal?", at which point matrix rotations will need to be performed to ensure the solution, and test possible variants.) Is it easier to start with a clean state every time, or carefully undo everything you did?

Another callout about purity is to avoid the headaches of randomness.
If the state is consistent, but the view is presented differently each time because of some randomness/impurity, it becomes increasingly difficult to test.

Answer (score 1):

> UI or the view layer is most predictable when it is described as a
>   pure function of the application state

The idea in about separation of concern.

So the UI responsibilities are:
- Display the data passed.
- Detect user interaction, like on click.

Logic for the UI in redux is usually achieve in the containers and related modules.
The container pass the data to the UI.